# HTML-based script recording using IE11 browser does not generate web_submit_data events

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I am trying to record a web application using Vugen Recording Option - HTML based script with HTML Advanced option of "Script type - A script describing user actions". With IE10 browser, I am able to record web_url and web_submit_data statements. With the IE11 browser, when I record the same application, I see only web_urls recorded. I personally find it easy to parameterize or correlate values with web_submit_data.

How do I record the same events in the IE11 browser?

Also, is there any way to convert the web_url statements to web_submit_data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: does the script work correctly without the web_submit_data calls? It will help if you could post an example of a particular web_submit_data call that was transformed into web_submit_url so that we can see if it is an error or the proper flow